adjust geom_col so bars are in same direction
I am plotting the values of a variable that have a wide range, so I've chosen to use a logarithmic axis for the values. However, when I use geom_col with the logarithmic axis, it flips the direction of all values < 1.  How can I adjust this, so that all the bars start at the same point (like 0.01 instead of 1) and plot in the same direction?
data.frame(cat = LETTERS[1:10],
           val = runif(10, 0.001, 10)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = val, y = cat)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(0.2, 0.1, 1, 2, 5, 10),
                labels = c(0.2, 0.1, 1, 2, 5, 10))


Bonus questions:

Why are only some labels showing up?
How can I use some version of scale_fill_??? get values <1 to be a different colour without creating another variable?


How about using abs()?

@Kat how would you use it?

The documentation for geom_bar notes:

Proceed with caution when using transformed scales with a bar chart.
It's important to always use a meaningful reference point for the base
of the bar. For example, for log transformations the reference point
is 1. In fact, when using a log scale, geom_bar() automatically places
the base of the bar at 1.

If you do want to proceed, one option is to transform with log1p which is simply log(x + 1).
library(ggplot2)


set.seed(4)

data.frame(cat = LETTERS[1:10],
           val = runif(10, 0.001, 10)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = val, y = cat, fill = val < 1)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = scales::transform_log1p(),
                     breaks = c(0.2, 0.1, 1, 2, 5, 10),
                     labels = c(0.2, 0.1, 1, 2, 5, 10)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = 'none')



Thanks @Seth.  I've tried running this code, but I'm getting the following error message: Error: 'transform_log1p' is not an exported object from 'namespace:scales'.

Hi @tnt, you can try scales::log1p_trans(). What version of scales are you using? I'm on version 1.3.0.

I'm using v 1.2.1.

I just tried the option you suggested and it works, but the x-axis doesn't appear to be truly logarthimic. From 1-100 it's fine, but any values < 1 are not displayed as logarthimic values.

I'm not sure how best to describe it, but a logarithmic axis should have evenly spaced breaks between 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, etc., but this approach is not spacing things evenly.
